# Comparing identical strings return false

Tags: .net, vb.net, io

I want to code a function which checks my ip. If my ip is `22.161.121.238` or checking gave `Exception` it sleep the current thread and starts checking again.

That's the code:

```
Private Sub CheckIp()
    Dim ip As String
    Dim mine As String = "22.161.121.238"
    Try
        Do

        Using wc As New Net.WebClient

            ip = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(wc.DownloadData("http://tools.feron.it/php/ip.php"))
        End Using


        If String.Equals(ip, mine) Then
            MessageBox.Show("2")
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("@" & ip & "@ is not equal to @" & mine & "@")
            End If
        End If

    Loop While ip = "22.161.121.238"


Catch ex As Exception
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
    CheckIp()

End Try

End Sub
```

I have no idea why does it not showing "2" from `MessageBox`. Even when `ip` and `mine` are identical, it does not launches `Show` method. Can you tell me why?

## Edit

What I get after launching a button is (I added `@` to see where the string starts):

[image]

Comment: How are you determining that `ip` and `mine` are identical? I'm guessing they actually aren't.

Comment: You should maybe consider using the [`IpAddress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress(v=vs.110).aspx) clas it won't magically solve things but it can ease them (and is a more robust way of doing things

Comment: sstan, wny don't you fire up visual studio, copy the code and test the values like I did, your assumption is completely wrong.

Comment: I should do that earlier, but I added a gif to first post.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that your 2 strings are **not** identical.  They may seem identical, but the string you are getting back from the web resource is including the ***non visible*** [Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/FEFF/index.htm) at the beginning of your string (I checked).

To confirm, check the numeric value of the individual characters of the returned string, specifically, the first character.

As a workaround, you can use @henry's answer which uses a different way of comparing strings, which will ignore the `u+feff` character.

Alternatively, you can strip it out explicitly for the equality check:

```
If String.Equals(ip.Replace(ChrW(&HFEFF), String.Empty), mine) Then
```

However, if you are the author of the PHP page, you probably want to fix it so that it doesn't return the `u+feff` character in the first place.

Comment: these type of question and answer are popular these day :-) already answer a few of these in the past few months +1 btw

Comment: Hence, you have to use the string.compare function :)

Comment: The OP, doesn't care if they are equal in the definition of true equal.

Comment: @henry: That's your interpretation. When I see a title that says: *Comparing identical strings return false*, and then the question *Can you tell me why?*, I think that the correct answer is *because the strings are not actually identical*. If OP wants workarounds, ok. But I would never want to give anyone the incorrect impression that `String.Compare(s1, s2) == 0` is a valid way of checking for *identical* strings.

Answer (score -1):

Try this function, you had some if/then logic in your original function that wasn't correct.

```
Private Sub CheckIp()
Dim ip As String
Dim mine As String = "22.161.121.238"
Try
    Do

    Using wc As New Net.WebClient

        ip = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(wc.DownloadData("http://tools.feron.it/php/ip.php"))
    End Using


    If string.Compare(ip, mine) = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("2")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
    Else
            MessageBox.Show("@" & ip & "@ is not equal to @" & mine & "@")
    End If


Loop While ip.Contains("22.161.121.238") 


Catch ex As Exception
Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000)
CheckIp()

End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: `String.Equals` checks for binary equality (which is what OP seems to want), where as `String.Compare` checks for sort order and will be affected by the current culture.

Comment: String.Equals doesn't compare reference (like most Equals) because String is a class **but** with "value type behaviour" so Equals is the same as == operator

Comment: Why downvote my answer, it's 100% correct. Sstan, I tested my answer in code an your comment is completely false about what the OP wants.

Comment: `String.Compare` can return `0` for 2 strings that logically sort the same, but that are not necessarily equal. How is that correct?

Comment: If you look at the source for `String op_Equality` (i.e. ==), it is implemented by returning the results of `string.Equals(a, b)`.

Comment: Tell you what... why don't you post a reproducible code example of 2 strings that are equal, and where `String.Equals` produces the wrong result, but `String.Compare` produces the right result.  If you can do that, I will gladly upvote.

Comment: @henry: Saw the video. Gotta say, that was nice.  I'll just ask for one more thing.  Can you check the *length* of `ip` and `mine` as well?  What do you get?  Do they match?

Comment: Length is 14 vs 15 (because of the non-printable character) - but using the compare function is the quick solution, or else you'll have to strip those characters, before you do the equals compare. In some cases you might not want to strip them.

Comment: Let's just agree we are both correct and that I made you spend the extra effort and explaining the why? Which I didn't do.

Comment: Ok, so we agree that the 2 strings are *not* identical.  My problem was that OP thinks that the 2 strings are identical and that `String.Equals` is somehow broken.  Your answer feeds that incorrect notion even further by simply stating that he's using the wrong function and cryptically implying that `Equals` doesn't do what he thinks? Don't you think it would be much more useful to explain why his code didn't work (strings are not identical), which is OP's question. And then if you want to suggest a practical workaround, then by all means...

Comment: That depends on which definition of identical you're using, in scientific terms they are not. But in the visual sense they are. The OP see the visual, not the scientific.  Based on how the OP wants to compare in the visual sense the OP is using the wrong function. I knew how the OP was comparing, because I took the time to test what the OP was seeing. Were your original assumption was incorrect on your first comment. Until you investigated further to see what I already knew. Now I didn't explain the why, but you could of simply commented, can you please explain the why instead of downvote.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Of course it was just visual similarity. The thing is I coded in vb very long time ago and that bug was annoying me. henry, unfortunelly changing to your code does not repair my problem. You can look at the edit in first post. With your code everything stays the same.

Comment: @audiophonic Try the revised code I posted, it should work.